# Rails turbolinks submit remote true forms multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

Using turbolinks and submitting remote true forms causing an issue is that forms submitting multiple times.

Like when I visit pages multiple times and then submit a form which is submitting remotely. It submits multiple times. This issue is due to turbolinks as the section of the Turbolinks README [Working with Script Elements](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#working-with-script-elements) advises avoiding inline scripts when installing event handlers:

Here is my form code

```
<%= form_for 'user', :url => otp_path, :html => { :id => "user_login_form1" }, :remote => true, format: :json do |f| %> 
   <%= f.submit "Submit", id: 'user_login_form1_submit','data-disable-with' => 'Progressing...' %>
<% end %>
```

and in same view I am submitting it using jquery

```
$(document).on('click','#user_login_form1_submit',function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    jQuery('form#user_login_form1').submit();
});
```

I don't want to remove turbolinks from my site ut how to deal with remote true form submitting  multiple times issue?

Comment: Show some code, show the form, something.

Comment: @arieljuod please check again... updated

Comment: What's the expected behaviour of your code? `rails-ujs` (or `jquery_ujs`) tries to handle the form submission if you set `remote: true` and `disable_with: ...` options. You don't need to listen the click event. Can you clarify your intention? use either the rails options (`remote`,`disable_with`,`format`) or the jquery callback, but not both.

Comment: I tried without disable_with and also without click event.

Comment: faces same issue

Comment: @arieljuod i am doing some processing and validations in click function and then submit

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add some validations without loosing the rails handler, do something like this:

```
$(document).on('ajax:before','#user_login_form1', function(ev) {
  let valid = .....
  if (!valid) return false;
});
```

Check the docs (I guess you are using jquery_ujs): https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#stoppable-events

If you use rails-ujs, then do `ev.preventDefault()` or `stopEverything(ev)`.